# Is "for each" guaranteed to work with altering arrays?

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, flash, loops, foreach

1) In AS3, are counter-less loops like ***for each*** guaranteed to work if the array in question changes during the ***for...*** loop? By changes I mean inserting/removing elements from the array

2) If an element is inserted in the array after the loop has executed half-way through, will this element still be accessed by the ***for each*** loop?

3) Do any of the answers above apply to c++ ***for_each*** and C++11 range-based for-loop?

***EDIT :***

OK since it's obvious that counter-less loops are not smart anyway, does anyone know if there are ready-made smart libraries that won't fall over for either language? So that I won't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: An array by definition is not modifiable in its size. So, you can not insert elements in to an array. Do you mean any STL container, `std::vector` for example ?

Comment: Yes sorry, I was thinking AS3 and mixed their names!

Comment: [Iterator invalidation rules.](http://kera.name/articles/2011/06/iterator-invalidation-rules/)

Comment: Most languages make no guarantees about foreach when the array changes. C++ is one which will almost certainly fall over. Why are you asking about two entirely different languages though?

Comment: @Dave That's a personal question, anyway it's these 2 languages I am usually programming and I am developing similar libraries in parallel for both.

Comment: personal? erm, ok. Anyway I couldn't find any exact references, but the short answer would be: don't do it. Even in languages which support it, because there are 3 different (but all perfectly acceptable) ways for it to be implemented, so maintaining the code after you've forgotten, or when a new developer arrives, would be a nightmare.

Comment: Surely I am not translating from one language to the other instruction by instruction but yes, it would be nice to have ready-made smart iterators for each...

Comment: Also: adding elements during a foreach is usually a sign of a bad structure. Removing elements is quite a common requirement, and in those cases it's usually better to use `remove_if`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

Comment: @Dave Bad structure? This is common stuff in game logic (AI stuff etc)...

Comment: Well, I might have missed something, but I can't think of any case where it's required. If you mean pathfinding, you should be using a queue, not a foreach over an array. If you mean sprite rendering, that shouldn't be spawning new sprites (game logic and rendering should be separate)

Comment: It's late here and I need to go to sleep but for example, it's a list of actions that either destroy other actions (of the same list) or provoke new ones to be created (in the same list) which must also be immediately iterated.

Comment: actions should be in a queue, where you have a loop which pops from the head of the queue for processing, and you push to the tail (you could also push to the head). It's more optimal than an array with a foreach, because you free space as you iterate (for optimal performance in ActionScript, use an array and two variables; one for the head position and one for the length. As you pop items, don't remove them from the array, but increment the head position and reduce the length. Obviously needs special logic for resizing the array when it's too small. C++ has the deque type built-in for this)

Comment: (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/ for details. Double-ended queue: you can push to head/tail and pop from head/tail in O(1) time, unless a reallocation is needed in which case pushing is O(n) since it needs to copy the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test shows that the AS3 version is not smart at all:

```
var a:Array = [0,1,2];
for each (var b:Number in a) {
    trace(b);
    if (a.length < 10) a.unshift(b+10);
}
```

Result:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
```

It iterates over the same element again and again.

So parts 1 and 2 of my question are answered (no, it's far from guaranteed). Anyone knows about 3?

***EDIT:***

Same applies for C++, need to make a custom loop to avoid iterator invalidation.

As Mahesh stated:
http://kera.name/articles/2011/06/iterator-invalidation-rules/

Comment: You can try with `push()` instead of `unshift()`, that will end elements in the end of an array, so that they will likely be iterated. Also, it's one of the normal cases of `for each` use as you describe, that is triggering more actions that too should be iterated through. See, a trigger is a consequence, so it should be iterated after a certain action.